# rails 5.0.1 already initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, upgrade, updates

I tried to generate a user but it appears this error, if i give a `rails s` the same error appears, i cant do anything, i gave a `bundle update`, a `bundle install` in the gems and nothing changes. I changed the version of rails in the `GEMFILE` of `4.6.2` to `5.0.1` and gave a `bundle update`. I wanted to work with version 5 , but i dont know how to update, i saw a tutorial that said i could do it like this, so i did,  only now this error appears.

```
root@ubuntu:~/Projeto-video-3# rails model User name document kind status:integer notes:text
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::Signer
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::TEXT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCERTS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSIGS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCHAIN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOINTERN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::DETACHED
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOATTR
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSMIMECAP
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_PADDING
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::SSLV23_PADDING
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::NO_PADDING
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::EC::NAMED_CURVE
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ExtConfig::HAVE_TLSEXT_HOST_NAME
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ExtConfig::TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_OFF
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_CLIENT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_APPLICATION_VERIFICATION
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_IGNORE_CRITICAL
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_X509_STRICT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_ALLOW_PROXY_CERTS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_POLICY_CHECK
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXPLICIT_POLICY
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_INHIBIT_ANY
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_INHIBIT_MAP
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_USE_DELTAS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NO_ALT_CHAINS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_CLIENT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_SERVER
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_NS_SSL_SERVER
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_SIGN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_ENCRYPT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_CRL_SIGN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_ANY
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_OCSP_HELPER
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_TIMESTAMP_SIGN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_COMPAT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_CLIENT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_SERVER
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_EMAIL
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OBJECT_SIGN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_SIGN
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_REQUEST
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_TSA
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_AREA
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR_ENV
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE_ENV
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_PRIVATE_DIR
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_INTERNALERROR
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_MALFORMEDREQUEST
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_NOSTATUS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SIGREQUIRED
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized 

    constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_TRYLATER
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_AFFILIATIONCHANGED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CACOMPROMISE
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CERTIFICATEHOLD
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CESSATIONOFOPERATION
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_KEYCOMPROMISE
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_REMOVEFROMCRL
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_SUPERSEDED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCERTS
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOINTERN
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOSIGS
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHAIN
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOVERIFY
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOEXPLICIT
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCASIGN
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NODELEGATED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHECKS
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::TRUSTOTHER
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPID_KEY
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOTIME
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_GOOD
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_REVOKED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_UNKNOWN
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_NAME
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_KEY
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RSA
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DSA
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DH
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RAND
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_CIPHERS
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DIGESTS
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_ALL
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_NONE
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSAL_TAG_NAME
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EOC
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BOOLEAN
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::INTEGER
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BIT_STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OCTET_STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::NULL
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OBJECT
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OBJECT_DESCRIPTOR
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EXTERNAL
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::REAL
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::ENUMERATED
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EMBEDDED_PDV
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UTF8STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::RELATIVE_OID
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::SEQUENCE
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::SET
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::NUMERICSTRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::PRINTABLESTRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::T61STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::VIDEOTEXSTRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::IA5STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UTCTIME
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GENERALIZEDTIME
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GRAPHICSTRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::ISO64STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GENERALSTRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSALSTRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::CHARACTER_STRING
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BMPSTRING
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_1024
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_1024 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_2048
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_2048 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of AES was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::CAST5
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of CAST5 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::BF
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of BF was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::DES
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DES was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::IDEA
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of IDEA was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.4/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    rails aborted!
    TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Cipher
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/Rakefile:4:in `require'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    /root/Projeto-video-3/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:3:in `load'
    bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Try prefixing your `rails generate` with `bundle exec`

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: `bundler exec rails g model User  name document kind status:integer notes:text  `

Comment: this gave to me the same error

Comment: It looks like `Cipher` is defined differently in OpenSSL in rails 5 dependencies. Try following this guide: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Upgrading is more complex than changing the rails version in the gemfile.

Comment: I have tried it but when i give a `rails app:update task` or `rake rails:update` doesnt work, one of the same error that gave before and the other of the unrecognized command, i dont know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve it, but I managed to get around the problem, after I generated the project, I enter the gem file and change the version of rails, and I put the version of ssl that runs on my machine.

```
gem 'openssl', '2.0.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '4-2-stable'
```

after putting it, make a bundle install the wheel design.